# Chartist not defined error in Node / express app

Tags: node.js, chartist.js

I am trying to use Chartist in a Node app using ejs to render my HTML . I am using the Chartist CDN and have included the necessary scripts etc in my header.ejs and set up my data model in the main.ejs file I want to render. However I keep getting "Chartist not defined error". I have tried moving the script tag into my footer, as per another answer on SO, but that didn't work either. My header.ejs and main.ejs are as follows. Is there something I am missing?

header.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
```

And main.ejs

```
<%- include('partials/header') %>
<h1>GRAPH</h1>

<div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth"></div>
<% let data = {
  labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
  series: [
    [5, 2, 4, 2, 0]
  ]
};
%>
<% new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data); %>

<%- include('partials/footer') %>
```